# Blink sketch isn't clear to me

Tags: c, arduino, led

The code job is for Arduino to blink, alternating between fast blinks and slow blinks. The LED should blink 5 times, once every half second, and then it should blink 5 more times, once every two seconds. The LED should continue to blink in this alternating fashion for as long as the Arduino receives power.

```
// Pin 13 has an LED connected on most Arduino boards.
// give it a name:
int led = 13;
bool isChange=true;

void setup() {
  // initialize the digital pin as an output.
  pinMode(led, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  for(int i=0;i<5;i++) {
    digitalWrite(led,HIGH);
    // turn the LED on (HIGH is the voltage level)
    if(isChange)
      delay(500);
    else
      delay(2000);
    digitalWrite(led,LOW);
   // turn the LED off by making the voltage LOW
    if(isChange)
      delay(500);
    else
      delay(2000);
  }
  isChange=isChange?false:true;
}
```

I don't get how the loop executes 10 times and how `ischange` works in the last line in code.

Comment: Keep learning. Try to understand this simply program yourself. As a hint last line is an equivalent of `isChange = !isChange;`. Learn about `?` operator in C

Comment: the inner loop runs 5 times, this should be obvious from the code. `isChange` is clearly a misnomer, and should be called something like `shortInterval` to make the code more self-describing. And then, as @PeterJ commented, the last line just toggles `isChange` in an IMHO unreadable way, `isChange = !isChange` would be much better.

Comment: This may be out of the scope you're currently interested in, but a *sane* implementation of the requirement would use a hardware timer and interrupt service routines to toggle the LED. This solution here completely hogs the CPU for such a simple task.

Comment: @Felix Palmen it is the Arduino community. Do not expect too much ... YT learning

Comment: @PeterJ 
i know c basics and searched for `?` before asking but i just don`t get how the value of ischange change if there is some program that can view the values changing with every step provide me a link ?

Answer (score 1):

When you reach the end of the loop() function the arduino will call it again, making the for-loop start all over again. This is why it blinks more than five times.

```
ischange = ischange ? false : true;
```

is called a **ternary operator**. It is syntactic sugar for

```
if (ischange)
    ischange = false;
else
    ischange = true;
```

It can be generalised to

```
condition ? expression A : expression B
```

If the condition is true, expression A is executed, else expression B. The result of this expression can be captured by an assignment operator, such as in the case in your code.

```
type variable_name = condition ? expression A : expression B
```

Comment: what will make `isChange` value to be changed in order to execute `delay(2000) ?`

Comment: The ternary operator? I am not sure if i can explain it any more clearly than i just did.

Comment: The ternary operator evaluates to a new value based on condition. This result is then assigned to `isChange`. This creates alternating values for `isChange`

Comment: appreciate your answer .Thanks